# Processing a tab delimited file with shell script processing

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, sed, awk

normally I would use Python/Perl for this procedure but I find myself (for political reasons) having to pull this off using a bash shell.

I have a large tab delimited file that contains six columns and the second column is integers. I need to shell script a solution that would verify that the file indeed is six columns and that the second column is indeed integers. I am assuming that I would need to use sed/awk here somewhere. Problem is that I'm not that familiar with sed/awk. Any advice would be appreciated.

Many thanks!
Lilly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can directly tell `awk` what the field delimiter is (the -F option).  Inside your `awk` script you can tell how many fields are present in each record with the NF variable.

Oh, and you can check the second field with a regex.  The whole thing might look something like this:

```
awk < thefile -F\\t '
{ if (NF != 6 || $2 ~ /[^0123456789]/) print "Format error, line " NR; }
'
```

That's probably close but I need to check the regex because Linux regex syntax variation is so insane. (*edited because grrrr*)

Comment: Pointy, you are a saint. (So are you Ignacio). Works great!

Answer (score 3):

gawk:

```
BEGIN {
  FS="\t"
}

(NF != 6) || ($2 != int($2)) {
  exit 1
}
```

Invoke as follows:

```
if awk -f colcheck.awk somefile
then
  # is valid
else
  # is not valid
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

here's how to do it with awk

```
awk 'NF!=6||$2+0!=$2{print "error"}' file
```

Comment: wow my mind is expanding - I've been awking for almost 30 year without knowing you can drop an expression out there where a regex would go

Answer (score 2):

Pure Bash:

```
infile='column6.dat'
lno=0

while read -a line ; do
  ((lno++))
  if [ ${#line[@]} -ne 6 ] ; then
    echo -e "line $lno has ${#line[@]} elements"
  fi
  if ! [[  ${line[1]} =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] ; then
    echo -e "line $lno column  2 : not an integer"
  fi
done < "$infile"
```

Possible output:

```
line 19 has 5 elements
line 36 column  2 : not an integer
line 38 column  2 : not an integer
line 51 has 3 elements
```